# Lower bound for Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, stirling-numbers

I'm doing some research in a different area of math and I need the following answered:

Let $s_{n,k}$ denote the unsigned [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), $0 \leq k \leq n$. Does there exist a constant $C > 0$ such that for all $k,n$, $$s_{n,k} < C^n(n-k)!$$

I hope the answer is no.

Any pointers towards the relevant literature would be appreciated too.

Comment: so, it is an Upper bound

Comment: The second equation ("for fixed $n$ we have the following estimate as $k\to\infty$...") on [this Wikipedia page section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Asymptotics) seems to contradict the inequality you describe.